# git push to local harddrive repo requires ssh? (cygwin)

Tags: git

I have the following setup:

s:/git/java/myproj.git with

```
git --bare init
```

s:/_java/myproj/.git with

```
git init, git add .
```

I added

```
git remote add origin s:/git/java/myproj.git
```

and tried to do:

```
git push origin master
```

And am getting:

error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

Why does git try to use ssh? I think I read that git accepts local paths on any command that specifies url.

Fixed: it has to do with a requirement to use cygwin drive path.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by s:/git ... is your harddrive named s?
If you want to use git locally just don't add a remote and commit only. Because you are not pushing local changes anywhere which is the purpose of git push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin doesn't understand drive letters with colons, so ssh thinks you are trying to contact a host named `s` (with `s:/git/...`). Instead, try:

```
git remote add origin /cygdrive/s/git/java/myproj.git
```

The key is to use something that looks like a Unix path name, rather than a hostname:pathname pair.